# How to stick UIButton to the bottom of UIScrollView? (Chatto framework)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton, chat

I want to create such a UI that have two buttons stick to the bottom of the screen and a UIScrollView above them. I am using Chatto framework and would be great if anyone could give me an example how to do that based on https://github.com/badoo/Chatto/tree/master/ChattoApp/ChattoApp.

Here is the visualization of view that I'd like to have.

[image: What i would like to get]

Comment: you should not stick the buttons to the scrollview but you should stick it to the ui view and scrollview should be above buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this using constraints. If you're using storyboard, you can set the constraints up using their "Pin" and "Align" features. If you're building it in code, you'll want to programmatically set up your constraints. Just be sure to add all the necessary constraints to fully define how the view should appear.

pseudo example with just one button:

```
let button = UIButton()
self.view.addsubview(button)
// pin button to bottom of superview, 
let buttonBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
self.addConstraint(buttonBottomConstraint)
// left of superview, 
// right of superview, 
// and height

let scrollView = UIScrollView()
self.view.addsubview(scrollView)
// and bottom edge to top edge of button
let scrollViewBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: button, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
self.addConstraint(scrollViewBottomConstraint)
// left of superview, 
// right of superview, 
// pin scrollview to top of superview,
```

Answer (score 3):

there is a better solution for this. you can do this by disabling the Auto Layout(button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false) property of the corresponding Button or any UIView for floating button:

Swift 4 example

```
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
     button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
     button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
} else {
     button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.layoutMarginsGuide.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
     button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a full screen scrollview then add a UIView across the bottom (anchoring to bottom of screen). Then add the 2 buttons to the UIView.

If you want to make it semi transparent then make the UIView background color to be clearColor and then add a UIView with alpha of say 0.6 and add this to your original UIView above the buttons.